# How to detect the cross in the center?

Tags: image-processing, fourier-analysis

No matter how I rotate this image, it has a cross in its spectrum. Is there a good way to detect the cross in the center?

```
im = ColorConvert[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEmIR.png"], "Grayscale"];
Manipulate[ImageAssemble[{r = ImageRotate[im, deg, Background -> 1], 
   gram = ImagePeriodogram[r]}], {deg, 0, 90 °}]
```

[image]

As my try, the `ImageLines` has a very bad ability

---

ps: Or [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BFcV.png)

Comment: I only tried for vertical and horizontal lines, but If you know in advance the orientation of the cross then something like `HighlightImage[gram, ImageLines[DerivativeFilter[gram, {0, 1}], MaxFeatures -> 1]]` adapted to a specific orientation might work.

Comment: This is where I would start:

```
(*Load and adjust image*)
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEmIR.png"];
img = ColorNegate[img];
img = Binarize[img];

(*Identify the connected components in the image*)
components = MorphologicalComponents[img];

(*Remove any enclosed components*)
gridComponent = 
 SelectComponents[components, #EnclosingComponentCount == 0 &];

gridComponent//Image
```

Answer (score 6):

Try preprocessing the periodigram before applying ImageLines. Binarization seems to work pretty well. With your image im:

```
im = ColorConvert[
     Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEmIR.png"], "Grayscale"];
Manipulate[
    ImageAssemble[{r = ImageRotate[im, deg, Background -> 1], 
    gram = ImagePeriodogram[r]}]; 
    lines = ImageLines[Binarize[gram, Method -> "Entropy"], MaxFeatures -> 2];
    HighlightImage[gram, lines], {deg, 0, 90 °}]
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I just not very like the magic 0.7 :)

Comment: Method->"Entropy" and Method -> "MinimumError" also work fine for the binarization step.

Comment: Elegant...You will get this bounty if you are not surprised

Answer (score 4):

**Very slow** but more precise:

```
im = ImageRotate[
   ColorConvert[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEmIR.png"], 
    "Grayscale"], Pi/10, Background -> 1];
gram = ImagePeriodogram[im];
dim = ImageDimensions[im];
center = Mean[PixelValuePositions[gram, Max[gram]]]
horlist = {#, 0} & /@ Range[First[dim]];
verlist = {First[dim], #} & /@ Range[Last[dim]];
```

[image]

Define a function to obtain pixel coordinates on a line to get the average pixel value along the bottom line:

```
pointsOnLine[{p1_, p2_}] := With[{d = p2 - p1}, 
  p1 + IntegerPart[#] + Round[FractionalPart[#]] & /@ (# d & /@ Subdivide[Max[Abs[d]]])]

ListLinePlot[Mean[PixelValue[gram, pointsOnLine[{center, #}]]] & /@ horlist, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

You get the points where the two lines have the highest mean:

```
maxpos = First[MaximalBy[#,Mean[PixelValue[gram, pointsOnLine[{center, #}]]] &, 
          1]] & /@ {horlist, verlist}
```

> {{353, 0}, {531, 294}}

Show the result:

```
HighlightImage[gram, {Thickness[0.005], InfiniteLine[{center, #}] & /@ maxpos}]
```

[image]